# Why did fluent assertion fail but Assert passed for an enum?

Tags: c#, assertion, fluent-assertions

I am having trouble finding why the assertion 1 fails but assertion 2 passed:

```
var a = Test.test1;
var b = Test.test1;
a.Should().BeSameAs(b); //1
Assert.Equal(a, b);     //2
```

`Test` is an enum like following:

```
enum Test { test1, test2 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Should()` for an `enum` resolves to `ObjectAssertions` which boxes the `enum` into an `object`.
For `ObjectAssertions` the `expected` parameter of `BeSameAs` is also of type `object`.

So `a.Should().BeSameAs(b)` boxes `a` and `b` into two different `object`s and then checks that those two objects refers to the *exact* same object in memory.

If you want to assert that `a` and `b` are the same `enum`, you should use

```
a.Should().Be(b);
```

Comment: Yes. Maybe the asker knows the same behavior with the static method inherited from `System.Object`. If you say `var q = ReferenceEquals(a, b);` then `q` will be `false`. Two different boxes with the same content.

Comment: @ Jeppe, The comparison with ReferenceEquals(a, b) really clarifies the issue. Thanks!